# Jmeter - How to compare two numbers using threshold

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my testing i need to compare two numbers, which are real numbers.

```
a) 0.070103 vs. b) 0.0701029999999999986
```

What is the best way to archive that, if possible with threshold included?

Answer (score 1):

How about rounding them?

Something like:

```
import java.math.MathContext

def a = 0.070103
def b = 0.0701029999999999986

def roundedA = a.round(new MathContext(5))
def roundedB = b.round(new MathContext(5))

log.info('Rounded a: ' + roundedA)
log.info('Rounded b: ' + roundedB)

log.info('Numbers are equal: ' + roundedA.equals(roundedB))
```

[image]

More information:

- [BigDecimal.round()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round(java.math.MathContext))
- [MathContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)